# Encoding Approach for Paired value

Tags: machine-learning, data-preprocessing

I'm having a problem with preprocessing my input data for later downstream analysis.
Example data:

```
#    Countries of parents    BMI    Education    Salaries
1    USA, UK                 23     Msc          5000
2    UK, Ukraine             24     Bsc          4500
3    Germany, France         23     Bsc          5500
4    France, France          25     PhD          6500
```

I want to encode the my data, however I'm having problem in the column with paired data ('Countries of parents). I did some review and found 2 solutions:

- Treat each pair as an individual value. However, I will lose the "paired" information, such as in #3 and #4, they both have "France".
- Use count vectorizer to encode the pair. This will retain the information of each pair, however, if the pool of values is too large, say a few thousand, then there will be too many dummy variable. Also the `MultiLabelBinarizer` of sklearn will transfrom the #4 into [0,0,...,1,...,0] while I want something like [0,0,...2,...,0]

I hope someone with expertise can help enlighten me on this problem, thank you very much.

Comment: For the first solution, do you intend to encode the country names as strings? Most algorithms are unable to take a string value (such as USA) as an input and will require you to convert the mother-country and father-country features into sets of dummy variables anyway.

Comment: Yes, after treating them as one single value instead of paired values, I will further encode them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hold the paired information and the number of categories are high it's is better to choose **Hashing** Encoding for unsupervised problem. **Target** Encoding(aka **Mean** encoding) for supervised problem. You can google about them for more information.

But as I said they can solve your problems,

a) Maintain the paired information and also

b) Resolves the high dimensionality issue(if you have large number of levels in your category variable)

Comment: Hi, I checked both target, but I didn't find how do they encode the paired value. Could you please show a simple example?

Comment: @ThanhNguyen each response will consider as a category(Ex: US, UK is considered as one category). Can you take a look at this https://github.com/ThisIsVenkatesh/Different_Versions_of_Mean_Encoding/blob/master/Mean_Encoding_implementation_in_python.ipynb for better understanding

Comment: Thanks for your informative notebook. I got the idea of mean encoding, however I still don't understand how the paired information is preserved if I treat (US, UK) as one category, because the will be totally different from (UK, Ukraine), even when they shared the same UK.

Comment: If you consider paired wise encoding you can't do analysis for a single country directly. There is a hack to do this but it is not recommended. Let's say we get mean encoding value for US,UK=3.3 and UK,Ukraine=5.3 , you can get the row of UK by considering encoding value 3.3 OR 5.3. This also means US,Ukraine. So that is why I said it's not recommended.

Comment: If you want to conduct a single country-wise analysis. I think in that case there is no need to go for paired wise countries. Please take a look at this https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/70188/how-to-do-target-encoding-when-data-has-repeated-rows/71374#71374 this may helpful.